# How to Send Data from one Azure IOT Device to another Device using different subscription

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Scenario : I have two different Azure Subscription with an Azure Resource of IOT Hub and multiple Devices each . My goal is I need to pick one device from IOT Hub and send those messages to another IOT Hub device(Different Subscription)

Difficulty : Sender IOTHUB Device ( can be an public / private ) , Receiver IOTHUB Device always run in private Vnet.

Any suggestions or solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

To send data from one Azure IoT device to another device using different subscriptions

- Create a route in the IoT Hub that specifies the destination IoT Hub.

[image]

Route Endpoint details.

[image]

- Send messages from the source IoT device to the source IoT Hub.
- Use Azure IoT Hub device streams to securely connect to the destination IoT device in the private VNet.

Using Power Shell

```
az iot hub devicestream create --hub-name <destination IoT Hub name> --device-id <destination IoT device ID> --resource-group  <destination resource group  name>
```

- Send messages to the destination IoT device
- using the device stream endpoint.

For further information refer to the [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c)